# Best way to handle Svelte component props

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css, svelte, sveltekit

I'm building an app using SvelteKit and Tailwind. I know that when using Tailwind to style it is recommended to leverage components to reduce the amount of repeated code you have to write using Tailwinds utility classes. My issue is that when making components based on HTML tags, for instance an `<input>` tag, dealing with props in that component that would normally just be attributes for that tag is getting overwhelming. MDN shows that the `<input>` tag has 31 possible attributes. I know that I won't be using all of them but going back and forth and adding them as props to a component is getting tiresome.

What is the best way to solve this problem without adding up to 31 lines of `export let attribute` to a component and adding them to the **real** HTML tag inside of the component?

Example:

```
<script>
    export let name;
    export let id;
    export let type;
    export let disabled;
    export let required;
    export let minLength;
    export let maxLength;
    export let min;
    export let max;
    export let pattern;

    let value;
    let borderColor = '#D1D5DB';

    const inputHandler = (e) => {
        if (e.target.value === '') {
            borderColor = '#D1D5DB';
        } else {
            borderColor = '';
        }
    };
</script>

<input
    {name}
    {id}
    {type}
    {disabled}
    {required}
    {minLength}
    {maxLength}
    {min}
    {max}
    {pattern}
    on:input={inputHandler}
    style={`border-color: ${borderColor}`}
    class="
    w-full px-1 py-px mb-4 bg-transparent border-2 border-gray-300 
    rounded-xl last:mb-0 valid:border-emerald-300 invalid:border-rose-400
  "
/>
```

Comment: you could export an object as prop and then spread it into the `input`

Comment: [repl](https://svelte.dev/repl/343b820fa857479196bd002ad5b9184f?version=3.48.0)

Comment: @pilchard this is absolutely the way to do it, you should write it up as an answer using your REPL code as a guideline

Comment: @pilchard The default values which are set on the exported variable get overwritten if the prop is passed on the component. So if just one value should be modified, all the values must be defined again in the parent. To prevent that I would suggest to seperate the default Options into a seperate object and spread both on the input element https://svelte.dev/repl/52715e3c326349fca4f310060869960b?version=3.48.0

Comment: Or probably even better - set the attributes which actually have a default value directly on the input element and spread the options afterwards https://svelte.dev/repl/062b19cdfc1a45409d66fbd1245609c6?version=3.48.0

Comment: @Corrl your last suggestion seems a good way forward, mine was a little off the cuff too late at night.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively to using the `$$restProps` (and based on @pilchard's comment above, thanks for that) an options object could be exported, which is holding all the modified attributes values and is spread after the default attributes defined on the input element inside the component
Like this all possible attributes of the element can be used/set without having to write them all out anywhere [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/062b19cdfc1a45409d66fbd1245609c6?version=3.48.0)

```
<script>
    import Input from './Input.svelte';

    const options ={
        type: 'number',
        placeholder:'input a number',
        required: true
    };
</script>

<Input {options} />
```

###### Input.svelte

```
<script>
    export let options = {}
    export let value = ''
</script>

<input type="text"
       placeholder="default placeholder"
       {...options}
       bind:value
       style:border-color="{options.required && value === '' ? 'tomato' : ''}"
       class="w-full px-1 py-px mb-4 bg-transparent border-2 ..."
       />
```

Comment: I'm curious, do you think that this would suffer from the same optimization problems as $$restProps since the props aren't explicitly defined? This solution and $$restProps are exactly what I'm looking for, minus the optimization problems and I'm likely going to go with one or the other.

I wonder if the optimization problems are referring to props that are reactive and are likely to change a lot, like value or possibly disabled. If so, using this solution or $$restProps wouldn't be a big deal for props such as placeholder or type since they are usually set once and not changed again.

Comment: Your solution for setting the border color if the value is empty is also much more succinct than my original solution! Thank you for the bonus optimization!

Comment: @Clarence I was also wondering if the 'kind of props' like you discribe make a difference with the optimization. Unfortunately I don't know enough from 'behind the scenes' yet to be able to tell if there are similar problems with the exported options version

Answer (score 5):

If you want to be able to do

```html
<MyInputField name="123" maxLength="5" type="text">
```

Without having to declare all these extra attribute, the best way to do so is to use the `$$restProps`, this object will contain all the props that have been passed to the component but have not been explicitly defined as props (exported).

```html
<script>
  export let name = "";
</script>

<input name={name} {..$$restProps}>
```

(here `name` was defined, so it will not be included in `$$restProps` and I had to add it myself)

Comment: You commented above that @pilchard's way is the one to do it. Is that because of the "optimisation problems" [the docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-attributes-and-props) state? *"It shares the same optimisation problems as $$props, and is likewise not recommended"*

Comment: That comment was not mine, but yes the optimization is an issue with props and restProps.

Comment: Oh my fault, both your names come up so often. Sorry for the confusion and thanks for answering!